# DFS-R not working, error 1753

Tags: windows, dfs-r

I would like to ask you about your opinions. I have two servers (both WS 2019, which are not domain controllers) where DFS replication is not working (at all). I'm getting error 1753: "There are no more endpoints available on endpoint mapper.". It's supposed to replicate all files on drive (D:). DNS is also configured properly and I'm out of ideas what to check next. Could you advise, please?

Already tried:

- restarted DFSR service
- rebooted both servers
- rebuilt whole DFSR config from scratch (also removed the replication group)

Thanks.

Comment: `1753: "There are no more endpoints available on endpoint mapper.` DFSR, as with any application that uses the RPC Endpoint Mapper, requires tcp/135, and dynamically registered port(s) from tcp/49152 through tcp/65535. What ports is your systems registering, and what does the network packet capture show on both of the systems?